# Ember 1.1x key-press event not responding to backspace

Tags: ember.js, keyboard-events

I am forced to use an older version of Ember and need to perform an action when a user types into a text field.

I've bound the action either by:

```
{{action="myAction" on="key-press"}}
```

or

```
{{key-press="myAction"}}
```

Both of these fire, except when I press backspace / delete to remove values. I need to event to fire in this use case.

Some googling turns up people suggesting using `key-up` or `key-down` but when I bind to those events in the same way as I've shown above, my action is never fired.

It feels like I'm missing something stupid here, any input would be greatly appreciated.

I'm afraid upgrading the Ember version is not an option.

EDIT:

I've managed to get the `keyUp` event firing using the following syntax, but this disables the firing of validation on my input field.

```
<input type="text" {{bind-attr class=":form-input errors.myField:error"}} {{bind-attr value=myField}} {{action "myAction" on="keyUp"}} />
```

On closer inspection when I look in Ember inspector the raw input I've just bound individual properties to doesn't appear as an `Ember.TextField` like the others on the form too. Which I presume is what's causing the validation not to fire.

Comment: try `{{action "myAction" on="keyUp"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For input helper if you are using `on` keyword then event names must be daserized.

```
{{input value="test" action="myAction" on="key-up"}}
```

For normal input element,

```
<input type="text" {{action "myAction" on="keyUp"}} />
```

**EDIT:**
For ember version 1.13 on wards `key-up` is working. like you said it's not working for older version 1.13. for this I would suggest to follow this,

Create my-input component which extends Ember.TextField and have keyUp function to handle keyUp event.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  keyUp(event){    
    console.log('keyup event',event);
  }
  //You can write keyPress and other functions too if required.
});
```

and you can use it `{{my-input value="test" action="myAction"}}` instead `input` helper.

**EDIT2**
You don't need to create Component just to make keyUp event to work that one is surely wrong one sorry for that. since there is a one more syntax to make it work,

```
{{input value="kumkan" key-up="keyUpFromApp"}}
```

define action in controller,

**controllers/applications.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  actions:{
    keyUpFromApp(value,event){
      console.log('keyup-event ',value, ' event ',event);
    }
  }
});
```

For reference, http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html#method_keyUp
To Play : [Ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1323d9e9852b4586c618bcc72fdaa1a7?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: In Ember 1.10 the dasherialised event name `key-up` never fires (nor does `key-down' but `key-press` is OK oddly.

I've managed to get the keyUp event working at per your second example but this seems to break my validation class binding :(

Comment: Updated answers to overcome this issue in earlier version.

Comment: I see. This makes sense, how would I go about firing the action bound to `key-up` I've tried a few approaches without any luck!

Comment: updated answers exactly what you are looking for. see EDIT2